# My Keyboard is going crazy in RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

I am running Windows 2008, anytime I connect to a PC with RDP..

My keyboard goes crazy.

Ex) If I type l in the RDP it will lock the Remote PC.

Any idea what might cause this?

I have checked the Regional settings and everything is correct and the keyboard language is correct. Everything is working correctly on my local PC with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Local Resources" tab of your RDP client, change the default "Keyboard" setting to another one.

Comment: I only see Keyboard - Apply key combinations (for example ALT+TAB).

Comment: That's it. Your problem is linked to a key combination sent to your server. With the default setting of the RDP client, the "Windows" key is often stuck. Windows + L => Lock

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me periodically - just whack the Windows key on your keyboard and that seems to sort it out.